# AWS Route 53 + Elastic Beanstalk + Certificate Manager: Wildcard (*) not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-certificate-manager

I set up SSL encryption for my Elastic Beanstalk environment's load balancer.
When I visit the base url it works. So

```
https://example.com
```

Works.
But when I visit:

```
https://www.example.com
```

the connection is not secure. I can't find the reason for this. I did get the certificate both for `example.com` and `*.example.com`.

I configured both addresses record sets over ip4 in the Route 53 hosted zones.

Comment: The exact information about why the connection is not believed to be secure would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't reproduce the issue anymore, since I resolved the issue by adding explicitly adding `www.example.com` to my certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding explicitly adding www.example.com to my certificate.

I don't like this workaround, but it does the trick I guess...

Comment: That definitely shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard record should work all case. You should check your Route53. Also, make sure don't use the Uppercase character in load balancer naming.